# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Question: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^2}^{e^x}\sqrt{1+r^2}~dr$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^2}^{e^x}\sqrt{1+r^2}~dr$$

How do I use fundamental theorem of calculus to solve this question? Can I split it up into $e^x$ and $x^2$ parts using different $u$'s and just subtract in the end (this is what I did but I don't think that's right)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the chain rule.  Say F is an antiderivative of $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.  Then the integral is $F(e^x) - F(x^2)$.  Now take the derivative of this using the chain rule and using that $F'(x)= \sqrt{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus gives 
$$d\int_{x^2}^{e^x} \sqrt{1+r^2}\, dr = \sqrt{1 + e^{2x}} d(e^x) - \sqrt{1+x^4} d(x^2)$$  that is $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^2}^{e^x} \sqrt{1+r^2}\, dr = e^x\sqrt{1 + e^{2x}} - 2x\sqrt{1+x^4}$$

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer that I got, but I didn't know it it was mathematically "legal" or not.

Comment: @RyanA, it is mathematically legitimate. sometimes it goes by the name of leibniz's rule.